# How do I override all stylesheets and scripts without a plugin

Tags: plugins, css, javascript

I'm finding that plugins completely destroy my source formatting and generally suck at following standards.

How can I absolutely block all style-sheets and move all .js to the footer of the site without modifying the plugins or adding an additional plugin?

Here's an example of what my homepage looks like under their rule http://pastebin.com/KRxRyYM7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress plugins usually enqueue's their stylesheets and js files using wp_enqueue_style and [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) functions. You can dequeue script / dequeue style the [scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script)/styles if you don't want them in your theme. These css/js files usually loads with wp_head() action, which usually resides in your header.php in the theme

Comment: +1, but I'd say that they *shouldn't* be enqueued/registered in header.php. this is stuff for functions.php.

Comment: wait, I'm confused. Wouldn't you always enque or register it in functions.php?

Comment: Yes, you can just use like this

`
function theme_dequeue() {
 wp_dequeue_script( 'KEY_NAME' );
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'theme_dequeue' );`

You just need to find out the KEY_NAME of that script when it was enqueued.